# How to get keys and values from a dictionary

Tags: c#

So I have a dictionary that is set up like:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Double>>
```

The date and times are months I pull from an excel spreadsheet and then my integers is the dollar amount. The columns look like this:

```
7/1/10 | 6/1/10
----------------
100.00 | 90.00
----------------
  3.00 | 20.00
----------------
 35.00 | 10.00
```

and so on and so forth for about 6 months. I need to get these keys and the values. I need to put it into my database. For example for the values 100.00, 3.00, 35.00 they all coordinate with month 7/1/10 (the first key has the 3 Values under it and etc.)

Could someone just show me how to iterate over these things? When I debugged my dictionary put's all the info in correctly but I can't pull them back out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate them directly in a nested loop

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Double>> map;
foreach (var pair in map) {
  DateTime dt = pair.Key;
  foreach (double value in pair.Value) {
    // Now you have the DateTime and Double values
  }
}
```

Comment: Gahhh to fast for me yo!

Comment: @AMR He's too fast for all of us. But this kind of question people will jump on.

Comment: @JaredPar hope you don't mind, I improved your answer by moving the `dt` declaration so it only is set once per value and its scope makes more sense.

Comment: @JaredPar seriously... You have 276k rep and 44 gold badges. Why don't you sit down for a little and let us lowly-grammers get in here and suck on the nipple a little. lol

Comment: @AMR can't ask an addict to stop being an addict ;).  Besides if I'm not posting here I have to do real work

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime,List<Double> pair in dictionaryName){
    DateTime dt = pair.Key;
    List<Double> doubleList = pair.Value;

    //With this method you now can step through each key value pair 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with linq:

```
 var myDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<Double>>();
 var julyValues= myDict.Where(r => r.Key == new DateTime(2010, 7, 1))
                       .Select(r => r.Value);
```

or with groupby:

```
var groupValues= myDict.GroupBy(r => r.Key)
                       .Select(grp => 
                               new { grp.Key, 
                                     values = grp.Select(r => r.Value) 
                                   }
                               );
```

Comment: This will only select the key, which is only helpful if you use it to select the values from the dictionary (I think you need to include that part to complete the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for singular values (if you know the key)

```
List<double> values = myDictionary[someDateValue];
```

And you can use a `foreach` for iterating through all the key pairs

```
foreach(var pair in myDictionary)
{
    DateTime keyValue = pair.Key;
    List<double> valueValue = pair.Value;
}
```